# Decrypting Rijndael 256 with Laravel 4

Tags: php, encryption, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to decrypt a String `UTlZecMS1NBtdDrDl/6tjw==` using Laravel 4 but it always gives me the error: DecryptException: Invalid Data.

My key is `11111111111111111111111111111111`.

But when I try to decrypt the data at [this site (scarlettcrypt)](http://scarlettcrypt.com/Rijndael), it successfully decrypts it. Please enlighten me. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
Crypt::setKey("11111111111111111111111111111111");
$s = Crypt::decrypt('UTlZecMS1NBtdDrDl/6tjw==');
return $s;
```

Comment: Seems like your encrypted string doesn't use an `iv`, so you'll probably need to extend the laravel crypt class to change the way it encrypts strings. You can specify the cipher type using `Crypt::setCipher('rijndael-256');`

Comment: @owlstead I'm not sure but I'm using the default from Laravel. (http://laravel.com/docs/security#encryption)

Comment: @Jeemusu sorry if I'm a newbie but what does iv mean? I think Laravel's Crypt pads something when encrypting and it expects some padding when decrypting. Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `iv` is an acronym of `initialization vector`. It is a randomized string that is used to further obfuscate the encrypted string. Laravel uses one by default, so you are in a way correct. You could either extend laravels Crypt library to account for that, or just use the mcrypt functions in php.

Comment: Oh for goodness sake, please ask Laravel to properly document their front ends. I cannot find a single mention on what the input and output arguments should actually be like. Just pointing to `mcrypt` and listing the modes is "a bit shallow".

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more @owlstead even if they just included links to actual implementation examples would be awesome. I think they do this so that laracasts gets more business, don't blame them Laravel is a pretty awesome free framework!